# GAE NDB Memcache - how to minimize cost of app with frequent writes

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached

I'm building a Reddit-style user-generated content website where users frequently vote on content submissions. Right now the app writes to the datastore every time a user votes to keep track of total vote count. I'm developing locally, but I imagine the cost would incredibly expensive to do so many frequent writes in a real deployed app.

How can I minimize the cost of this? I know NDB has automatic memcache but that is only for read operations and get operations.

Right now I'm thinking that the app will only write to memcache for each user vote, and then use Task Queue API to schedule a task everyday at Midnight that could make some sort of large batch write operation for all the votes count. Of course this would leave open the possibility that some data gets deleted from memcache and is not updated to the datastore.

Comment: Your votes are exceedingly unlikely to last more than a few hours and there is no garuntee on lifetime.  You would want a task running every few minutes to consolidate votes to the datastore.

Comment: I think you might be optimising for cost a bit prematurely, but if you wanted to stick with the batch write model without the risk of memcache eviction, you can enqueue votes on a pull queue and schedule a cron every hour (or less). Then you can aggregate the +/- votes into a net delta for each submission.  If you get a lot of votes, you can increase the cron frequency.

Comment: @tx802 Thanks very much. I'm still very new to using Task Queues and Cron Jobs. Would you be able to explain your solution in a little more detail (step-by-step)? Also, do you think this batch write model is the most efficient/effective?

Comment: @JK140 it depends on your definition of effective ;) e.g. using memcache atomic counters is efficient, but not effective if they get evicted.  If you were to run your cron job every few minutes it would more more effective but less efficient (more instance time & datastore writes). Also, if you get a *lot* of votes, you may end up with [hot memcache keys](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scalability#memcache_hot_keys). Will try to add an answer later.

Comment: @tx802 Thank you. Your help is very much appreciated

Comment: If you want to approach it this way and want reliable counting then you will need to pay for the reliable memcache service.

Comment: @TimHoffman I was going to follow tx802's advice and add all the votes initially to a pull queue and schedule a cron job every 10 minutes or so and do a batch write of all the votes data. Would this be efficient/effective?

Comment: @JK140 Yes, but choice of paid vs non paid memcahce will depend if you can afford to lose any votes.  Even in a 10 minute window (though unlikely) you could still lose data.